# Function to create a binary search tree recursively

Tags: python, class, recursion, binary-search-tree

[Picture of Question with specific details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wte7E.png)

I'm trying to write a function that creates a binary search tree. Here's what I have so far:

```
def add_items(bst, low, high):
    if low == high:
        bst.insert(high)
        return
    else:
        left = add_items(bst, low, high)
        right = add_items(bst, low, high)
        item = BinarySearchTreeMap.Item(low)
        node = BinarySearchTreeMap.BinarySearchTreeMap.Node(item)
        node.left = left
        node.right = right
        return node
```

The problems I noticed with this is that the function returns a node when it finishes all the recursive calls. I want to return the root of this binary search tree, but I'm not sure how to return it at the end. The picture includes a more detailed description of what I am trying to do. I appreciate any help, advice, or ideas anyone may have. add_items is actually sort of a helper function as it is called by this little snippet of code:

```
def create_complete_bst(n):
    bst = BinarySearchTreeMap.BinarySearchTreeMap()
    add_items(bst, 1, n)
    return bst
```

P.S. here is the binary search tree class that I have been provided with and am using in this program

```
class BinarySearchTreeMap:

class Item:
    def __init__(self, key, value=None):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value


class Node:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item
        self.parent = None
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def num_children(self):
        count = 0
        if (self.left is not None):
            count += 1
        if (self.right is not None):
            count += 1
        return count

    def disconnect(self):
        self.item = None
        self.parent = None
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


def __init__(self):
    self.root = None
    self.size = 0

def __len__(self):
    return self.size

def is_empty(self):
    return len(self) == 0


# raises exception if not found
def __getitem__(self, key):
    node = self.find(key)
    if (node is None):
        raise KeyError(str(key) + " not found")
    else:
        return node.item.value

# returns None if not found
def find(self, key):
    curr = self.root
    while (curr is not None):
        if (curr.item.key == key):
            return curr
        elif (curr.item.key > key):
            curr = curr.left
        else:  # (curr.item.key < key)
            curr = curr.right
    return None


# updates value if key already exists
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    node = self.find(key)
    if (node is None):
        self.insert(key, value)
    else:
        node.item.value = value

# assumes key not in tree
def insert(self, key, value=None):
    item = BinarySearchTreeMap.Item(key, value)
    new_node = BinarySearchTreeMap.Node(item)
    if (self.is_empty()):
        self.root = new_node
        self.size = 1
    else:
        parent = self.root
        if(key < self.root.item.key):
            curr = self.root.left
        else:
            curr = self.root.right
        while (curr is not None):
            parent = curr
            if (key < curr.item.key):
                curr = curr.left
            else:
                curr = curr.right
        if (key < parent.item.key):
            parent.left = new_node
        else:
            parent.right = new_node
        new_node.parent = parent
        self.size += 1


# raises exception if key not in tree
def __delitem__(self, key):
    node = self.find(key)
    if (node is None):
        raise KeyError(str(key) + " is not found")
    else:
        self.delete_node(node)

# assumes key is in tree + returns value assosiated
def delete_node(self, node_to_delete):
    item = node_to_delete.item
    num_children = node_to_delete.num_children()

    if (node_to_delete is self.root):
        if (num_children == 0):
            self.root = None
            node_to_delete.disconnect()
            self.size -= 1

        elif (num_children == 1):
            if (self.root.left is not None):
                self.root = self.root.left
            else:
                self.root = self.root.right
            self.root.parent = None
            node_to_delete.disconnect()
            self.size -= 1

        else: #num_children == 2
            max_of_left = self.subtree_max(node_to_delete.left)
            node_to_delete.item = max_of_left.item
            self.delete_node(max_of_left)

    else:
        if (num_children == 0):
            parent = node_to_delete.parent
            if (node_to_delete is parent.left):
                parent.left = None
            else:
                parent.right = None

            node_to_delete.disconnect()
            self.size -= 1

        elif (num_children == 1):
            parent = node_to_delete.parent
            if(node_to_delete.left is not None):
                child = node_to_delete.left
            else:
                child = node_to_delete.right

            child.parent = parent
            if (node_to_delete is parent.left):
                parent.left = child
            else:
                parent.right = child

            node_to_delete.disconnect()
            self.size -= 1

        else: #num_children == 2
            max_of_left = self.subtree_max(node_to_delete.left)
            node_to_delete.item = max_of_left.item
            self.delete_node(max_of_left)

    return item

# assumes non empty subtree
def subtree_max(self, curr_root):
    node = curr_root
    while (node.right is not None):
        node = node.right
    return node


def inorder(self):
    for node in self.subtree_inorder(self.root):
        yield node

def subtree_inorder(self, curr_root):
    if(curr_root is None):
        pass
    else:
        yield from self.subtree_inorder(curr_root.left)
        yield curr_root
        yield from self.subtree_inorder(curr_root.right)

def __iter__(self):
    for node in self.inorder():
        yield node.item.key
```

Comment: Why do you want to add the nodes _recursively_? The assignment doesn't require this.

Comment: I'm under the impression that a recursive solution would be easier. I did think about making an iterative solution, but also drawing a blank on that part.

Comment: The `BinarySearchTreeMap` class has already an `insert` method which creates item and node and places it at the right position in the tree. Your job would be just to call it repeatedly with all the numbers as keys (and probably `None` as values) that should be inserted.

Comment: I was originally going to do that but using the insert method of the class does not create a binary search tree with the correct structure that is shown in the picture.

Comment: For a balanced tree insertion calls must be made in the correct order: (1) check for `high < low` and just return (this case may happen during recursion). The `low == high` case remains as it is. (2) Set `middle = (low + high) // 2`. `insert` it. Then let the function recursively care about the range `low .. (middle - 1)` (which will create the left subtree) and `(middle + 1) .. high` (for the right). Should be enough. Creation of node or item object in the function isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After revising with suggestions:

```
def create_complete_bst(n):
    bst = BinarySearchTreeMap.BinarySearchTreeMap()
    add_items(bst, 1, n)
    return bst


def add_items(bst, low, high):
    if low == high:
        bst.insert(high)
        return
    elif high < low:
        return
    else:
        mid = (low+high) // 2
        bst.insert(mid)
        add_items(bst, low, mid-1)
        add_items(bst, mid+1, high)
        return bst
```